# Adding to Post contetnt by wpapi

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I'm using `wpapi` for `nodejs` to interact with my WP posts. I need to add some content to existed content of my `Post`. I'm trying to get content by `wp.posts()` but in `content` field of result I see only `rendered` result (so, no short codes there) and if I just will add some data to this content and PUT it back I will loose short codes. So maybe there is a way to just kinda `append` content, or get raw content as it is in WP.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use `.param('context', 'edit')` to get the raw content